# i want to generate return string function with looping for some index string

Tags: go

```
func change(a string) string {
    // fmt.Println(a)
    v := ""
    if string(a) == "a" {
        return "A"
        v += a
    }
    return ""
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(change("a"))
    fmt.Println(change("ab"))

}
```

i'm new at go and programming actually,
the output now is A, but why when i change the variable value to "ab" it returns no value it must be "Ab" for the output

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect? For `"a"` you want `"A"`, For `"ab"` you want `"Ab"`. What do you want for, say, `"abab"`?
For now, passing `"ab"` will mean that `string(a) == "a"` is `false`, and therefore the program will continue until `return ""`

Comment: it supposed to be "AbAb"

Comment: Why? What's the logic? Do you want any `a` to be uppercased anything else not?

Comment: There's no loop in your code. The `if` statement checks whether the input parameter `a` is equal to the string `"a"`, if it is you immediately `return "A"`, note that a `return` statement terminates the executing function and returns its argument list... So `v+=a` is never executed. Also if the input parameter `a` is NOT equal to `"a"` then you return an empty string. You also seem to be confusing the output you're reading in stdout, the actual output is `change("a")` returns nothing, i.e. empty string, and `change("ab")` returns `"A"`.

Comment: i mean, i wanna try to another alphabet like for vowels. sorry for the unclear question

Comment: and that's no need looping for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you basically want all `a`s in the input to be changed to `A`.
At the moment you just check whether the *whole* string equals `"a"`, and `"ab"` isn't equal to `"a"`. Therefore, the program ends up with `return ""` in the second case.

Normally, you can achieve what you want with something like `strings.ReplaceAll("abaaba","a","A")`. But for educational purposes, here's a "manual" solution.

```
func change(a string) string {
    v := "" // our new string, we construct it step by step
    for _, c := range a { // loop over all characters
        if c != 'a' { // in case it's not an "a" ...
            v += string(c) // ... just append it to the new string v
        } else {
            v += "A" // otherwise append an "A" to the new string v
        }
    }
    return v
}
```

Also note that `c` is of type `rune` and therefore must be converted to `string` with `string(c)`.

Edit: As noted in the comments, in practise that wouldn't be the best way to construct a new `string`. Appart from the hassle with the conversion from `rune` to `string`, we create a new `string` everytime we append something and drop the old one. Instead, we want to create an `string` only once - at the very end, when we know exactly how the result `string` shall look like.
Therefore, we should use a string builder instead. To avoid confusion, here's a separate example:

```
func change(a string) string {
    var resultBuilder strings.Builder
    for _, c := range a { // loop over all characters
        if c != 'a' { // in case it's not an "a" ...
            resultBuilder.WriteRune(c) // ... just append it to the new string v
        } else {
            resultBuilder.WriteString("A") // otherwise append an "A" to the new string v
        }
    }
    return resultBuilder.String() // Create the final string once everything is set
}
```

Comment: Do not append to a string in a loop. The running time is quadratic in the length of the input, which would be slow for a long one. Use a `strings.Builder` instead.

Comment: @jub0bs Yeah, I was wondering whether I should  "optimize" the joins as well. But since this is really just an educational/explanatory post for a beginner, I wanted to leave it as similar to the original one as possible. I mean, the clearest solution would be `strings.ReplaceAll()` anyway, right?

Comment: Yes. `strings.ReplaceAll` is likely the way to go. But especially if you leave the more involved solution as an example for educational purposes, you should show future visitors the better way (`strings.Builder`) 

Comment: Alright, allright, will mention it tomorrow! :)

Comment: Upvoted, but another nitpick: because `strings.Builder`'s zero value is readily usable, you can do `var resultBuilder strings.Builder`.